# End user input logic

Tags: python, logic

I am new to python and I have a conundrum which I cannot solve. Its a bit complicated to explain so bear with me!
I want the user to have the option of selecting the logic for A & B. (I have built this in pyqt5, with checkboxes on a small scale)
So the logic possibilities are as follows for A & B:

```
flag = ""
if A:
    flag = "1"
elif B:
    flag = "2"
elif A and B:
    flag = "3"
elif A or B:
    flag = "4"
else:
    flag = ""
```

Now that seems simple to code at those 2 variables. But I add only one more option - C:

```
flag = ""
if A:
    flag = "1"
elif B:
    flag = "2"
elif A and B:
    flag = "3"
elif A or B:
    flag = "4"
elif C:
    flag = "5"
elif A and C:
    flag = "6"
elif A or C:
    flag = "7"
elif B and C:
    flag = "8"
elif B or C:
    flag = "9"
elif A and B and C:
    flag = "10"
elif A or B or C:
    flag = "11"
elif A and B or C:
    flag = "12"
elif A or B and C:
    flag = "13"
else:
    flag = "etc etc"
```

Now I add in D, E , F, G. I don't know if the possibilities are truly exponential, but they are huge.
Now I am not the first person to have this issue and there must be a solution a novice like me is not aware of. For example, there are many workflow builder in PM tools like Jira, smart sheets, Salesforce, where the end user can define almost limitlessly the logic for triggers and actions.
But I cannot figure out for the life of me how to do this in code without pre-defining all the possibilities the end user may pick, beforehand
Hope this makes some sense? Any help or advice much appreciated on how the experts solve this particular issue.

Comment: The `and` and `or` cases will never run, since for either `A` or `B` (or both) need to be `True`, so that respective branch (`if A:`, or `elif B:`) would have been taken instead.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to have an `A or B` case when you also have `A` and `B` cases. If either of them is true, the flag should get that specific value, it can't get the `A or B` value.

Comment: Not sure but maybe you could create an integer value with these values as bits. For example, `A = True, B=False, C=True = 5` because `5 = 0b101`.

Comment: As otherones already commented, the order of the test is meaningful,  hence your logic seems flawed. With 'n' flags you have '2**n' cases and  @JohnnyMopp 's solution is applicable.

Answer (score 0):

Conditions in a sequence of `if/elif` are tested in order, so the more restrictive cases need to be first. E.g. both A and B are true, `if A:` will be successful, so that case will be executed, and you won't ever get to `if A and B:`

```
if A and B:
    flag = "3"
elif A:
    flag = "1"
elif B:
    flag = "2"
...
```

Also, it makes no sense to also have `elif A or B:` conditions when you also have conditions specifically for each of `A` and `B` alone, because the flag can't get both values.

Comment: Ok, as suspected my point was lost in translation. Logic syntax is not my query. After doing a bit more research I believe the general term is called a ‘query builder’ or a ‘logic builder’  where the end user has some basic knowledge of ‘AND ‘ ‘OR’ logic and they can chain together functions on the backend in any combination using the GUI, without the dev caring, of all the possible combinations. The issue I have is that the only way I know how to do this is ‘prepopulate’ all the possible combinations the end user may select. Meaning code could be millions of lines

Comment: This is usually done by translating the user input into nested dictionaries and lists that correspond to the operations, then using a recursive function that performs the corresponding logical calculations.